# how do I handle a state change event of CTreeCtrl in MFC

Tags: mfc

I'm a newbie of MFC programming and today I have trouble handling some event with CTreeCtrl.

To be more specific, i've enabled "check boxes" in CTreeCtrl's Properties, 
then I want to trigger callback function only when I change a item's state (checked/unchecked)  not just selecting items.

But I can only found some events who seems relevant like TVN_SELCHANGED and TVN_ITEMCHANGED, but the function VS.net generated are like

void OnTvnItemChangedTreeCtrl(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);

which makes me confusing 'cause I cant find out how to deal with this function as well as its parameters in MSDN.